# PARTITION BY statement on Conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I made a Query that uses `RowNumber()` to `PARTITION` a certain table, after which I only select the rows `WHERE RN = 1`. However I see now that my current query is insufficient, since the partition has to be dynamic, based on a condition.

My query results in the table below, however, some records shouldn't be included:

```
PROJID          ITEMID  AMOUNT                  STARTDATE   TAXITEMGROUPID  MODELID     RN
300.201343.01   4101    9648168.000000000000    20171004    Hoog            Budget      1
300.201343.01   4102    0.000000000000          20171004    Hoog            Budget      1
300.201343.01   4201    204541.000000000000     20171004    Hoog            Budget      1
300.201343.01   4202    195750.000000000000     20171004    Hoog            Budget_21   1
300.201343.01   4205    52933.460000000000      20171004    Hoog            Budget      1
300.201343.01   4211    278400.000000000000     20171004    Hoog            Budget_21   1
300.201343.01   4212    34800.000000000000      20171004    Hoog            Budget      1
300.201343.01   4215    620448.000000000000     20171004    Hoog            Budget_21   1
300.201343.01   4304    8400.000000000000       20151030    Geen            Budget_12   1 --shouldn't have RN = 1
300.201343.01   4304    8700.000000000000       20171004    Hoog            Budget      1
300.201343.01   4305    8700.000000000000       20171004    Hoog            Budget      1
300.201343.01   4307    130500.000000000000     20171004    Geen            Budget      1
300.201343.01   4307    154728.000000000000     20151030    Laag            Budget_12   1 --shouldn't have RN = 1
300.201343.01   4309    41322.310000000000      20150216    Hoog            Budget_5    1
```

For instance, I only want `ITEMID` 4304 to be partitioned by `TAXITEMGROUPID` when `STARTDATE` is also the same. When the `STARTDATE` is different, I only want it to be partitioned by `PROJID` and `ITEMID`.
So the RN should not be 1 in the latter case where `AMOUNT` = 8400.

This is the Query I currently use:

```
;WITH ApprovedBudget_Sales AS
(
    SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROJID, ITEMID, TAXITEMGROUPID ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC) RN
    FROM FORECASTSALES
    WHERE APPROVED = 1 --AND PROJID = '300.201343.01'
)
SELECT
    FORECASTSALES.PROJID
    ,FORECASTSALES.ITEMID
    ,FORECASTSALES.SALESQTY AS AMOUNT
    ,CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,ApprovedBudget_Sales.STARTDATE) AS [CHAR](4))
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(M,ApprovedBudget_Sales.STARTDATE) AS [VARCHAR](2)),2)  
       + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DATEPART(D,ApprovedBudget_Sales.STARTDATE) AS [VARCHAR](2)),2) AS STARTDATE
    ,FORECASTSALES.TAXITEMGROUPID
    ,MAX(FORECASTSALES.MODELID) AS MODELID
    ,RN
FROM FORECASTSALES
INNER JOIN ApprovedBudget_Sales
    ON ApprovedBudget_Sales.RECID = FORECASTSALES.RECID
    AND ApprovedBudget_Sales.DATAAREAID = FORECASTSALES.DATAAREAID
LEFT JOIN CATEGORYTABLE
    ON CATEGORYTABLE.CATEGORYID = FORECASTSALES.ITEMID
    AND CATEGORYTABLE.DATAAREAID = FORECASTSALES.DATAAREAID
WHERE ApprovedBudget_Sales.RN = 1 --AND FORECASTSALES.PROJID = '300.201343.01'
GROUP BY
    FORECASTSALES.DATAAREAID
    ,FORECASTSALES.TAXITEMGROUPID
    ,FORECASTSALES.SALESQTY
    ,FORECASTSALES.PROJID
    ,FORECASTSALES.ITEMID
    ,FORECASTSALES.ACTIVE
    ,CATEGORYTABLE.CATEGORYNAME
    ,ApprovedBudget_Sales.RN
    ,ApprovedBudget_Sales.STARTDATE
ORDER BY FORECASTSALES.PROJID, FORECASTSALES.ITEMID
```

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,
Igor

Comment: We could do with sample data and expected results as well as what you're currently getting. For instance, it's difficult to tell what you're looking for, since your narrative discusses 4303 - which isn't in the results you're showing us at all.

Comment: Excuse me, a typo, that had to be 4304. I edited the post.

Comment: So you want the row number of items that clash on the same date else always 1?

Comment: Yep, whenever they have a similar PROJID, ITEMID, TAXITEMGROUPID, STARTDATE, then partition PROJID, ITEMID, TAXITEMGROUPID. Whenever they have only a similar PROJID, ITEMID, TAXITEMGROUPID but the STARTDATE is different, then partition PROJID, ITEMID.

Comment: Why not use two ROW_NUMBER() funtions?

Comment: This indeed solves the problem!